# Slicing a pandas df using a numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This should be easy, but can't figure out the right syntax.  Let's say I get a numpy array of all NA locations for a particular column like so:

```
index = np.where(df['Gene'].isnull())[0]
```

I want to now examine those rows in the df.  I've tried things like:

```
df.iloc[[index]]
df[[index]]
```

To no avail.

Comment: Why not just mask the original DataFrame without numpy? `df[df.Gene.isnull()]` or `df.loc[index]` is how to slice it by an array of indices.

Comment: Why double square bracket? Simply `df.iloc[index]` for row slicing, `df.iloc[:,index]` for column slicing